# practical ArrayList example in java

Tags: java, arraylist

I am a new java student and would like to make a weather recording program using Arraylist that askes for input from user and displays maximum temperature and average temperature of the given days. I tried to make a loop structure and breaks from the loop when a certain number is given. Is there any way that this task can be done with out using different methods just in the main(I mean in public static void main(String[] args)). I tried something but I had Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: -1 error message. or if you have practical examples your most appreciated from a new be programmer. Thank you!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rF7yS.png)

Comment: Introduce us to your java code, the code you tried, explain what you expect and what you have a problem with.

Comment: Please share the code here so we can help you with the error. Here you are some documentation for beginners: https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_arraylist.asp

Comment: Please edit your question to include your code as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a pseudocode for your logic:

1. Prompt user for number of days to record
2. Set up a loop for the number of days
3. Ask user to enter temperature for that day
4. Insert the recorded value to ArrayList
5. After the Loop, use an enhanced for loop to iterate over the ArrayList
6. Calculate total temp
7. After the for loop, divide the total temp by the size of the ArrayList

The logic (pseudocode) can be used to calculate the average temperature

Comment: can you make sample code so that I get clear idea? thank you

Comment: Yes sure. How do u want me to share the sample code with you?

Comment: can it be here ?

Comment: Yes sure, i will add a sample code